# Delete Gitlab Backup Automatically

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, gitlab, backup

Hello wonderful people,

I am new in gitlab, jenkins and all this.

I am taking backup of whole gitlab everything including projects, branches and everything in backup . tar file with the help of jenkins everyday automatically.

I want to delete the backup periodically. Like I want to delete the backup after every 30 days. I want the last backup to be deleted automatically.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, as [mentioned in this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/24530), if you uncomment `gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time'] = 604800` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and reconfigure your GitLab, any [backup command](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html#back-up-gitlab) (like, For GitLab 12.2+, `sudo gitlab-backup create`) would delete old backups.

If you are able to ssh to your GitLab server, configure a Jenkins job which will execute that command

```
ssh <gitlabUSer>@gitlabServer sudo gitlab-backup create
```

Note: in your case, the setting `backup_keep_time` should be to to 2 592 000 (for 30 days instead of 7).

Comment: Will I need to add a job in jenkins for this ?
Or if I update the gitlab.rb file it will automatically get deleted ?

Comment: @SameerAtharkar You still need a job to call the `gitlab-backup create` command in order to trigger the backup. The setting I mention will make sure that, as part of this backup call, the final step will be to cleanup old backups (by default, they would not be removed at all)

Comment: I already have a jenkins job to take the backup. I do not need a special another job just to delete the backup. Right ?

Comment: @SameerAtharkar Correct, no other job needed in that case.

Comment: It is not working as per that @VonC
When I run the backup command is should delete the previously created backup as per the timeframe I mentioned right. 
It is not working that way..

Comment: @SameerAtharkar which timeframe did you specify, and did you reconfigure Forma after modifying the gitlab.rb config file?